# How do I get the payment status from the BuckarooSdk?

Tags: c#, .net, buckaroo

I'm trying to get the payment status of a payment. I've got the code below:

```
public bool HasBeenPayed(string transactionKey)
{
    var logger = new CustomLogger();
    var client = new SdkClient(() => logger);
    var request = client.CreateRequest().
        Authenticate(
            _websiteKey,
            _apiKey,
            _isLive,
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-nl"),
            BuckarooSdk.DataTypes.ChannelEnum.Web).
        TransactionStatusRequest().
        Status(transactionKey);

    var status = request.GetSingleStatus();
    var statusCode = status.Status.Code.Code;

    return statusCode == BuckarooSdk.Constants.Status.Success;
}
```

When I execute this, it freezes on executing `request.GetSingleStatus();`. It does not continue to the next line. The last thing logged in the custom `CustomLogger` is:

`The serialized request in JSON format is: null`

The [documentation](https://dev.buckaroo.nl/Sdks/netsdk) is limited, so I haven't found the answer there. There are not many Buckaroo posts on Stack Overflow either.

How do I get the status of a Buckaroo payment using the BuckarooSdk?

Comment: Buckaroo's .NET SDK is not too fun to use. Are you calling this code from MVC? The SDK uses `HttpClient.PostAsync/GetAsync`, and lots of `.Result` calls. May be a deadlock.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling this from MVC.